# Remove characters between in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string values like this

```
string strValue = "!return.ObjectV,rgmK12D;1.Value";
```

In this string how can I remove characters from `rgm to ;1`?

Below code will remove all the characters from rgm, but I need to remove upto `;1` only

```
strValue =  strValue.Substring(0, strValue.LastIndexOf("rgm"));
```

**Expected Result:**

```
string strValue = "!return.ObjectV,.Value";
```

**Edit 1:**

I am trying to remove the above mentioned characters from the below string

```
Sum ({rgmdaerub;1.Total_Value}, {rgmdaerub;1.Major_Value})
```

**Result**

```
Sum ({rgmdaerub;1.Total_Value}, {Major_Value})
```

**Expected Result**

```
Sum ({Total_Value}, {Major_Value})
```

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly you want this string to look like after removing not needed parts, currently for me is not clear.

Comment: @mybirthname - Updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
strValue = strValue.Substring(0, strValue.LastIndexOf("rgm")) + strValue.Substring(strValue.LastIndexOf(";1") + 2);
```

EDIT:

According to your edit, it seems you want all occurrences replaced. Also, your expected result has the "." removed as well. To replace all occurrences you can adapt from @Damith's answer:

```
strValue = Regex.Replace(strValue, "rgm.*?;1\\.", "");
```

Comment: why can't it be `strValue.Substring(strValue.LastIndexof("1")+1);`

Comment: @ThejakaMaldeniya - I have few issue with removing characters. Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

with regex

```
string strValue = "!return.ObjectV,rgmK12D;1.Value";
var output = Regex.Replace(strValue, @" ?rgm.*?;1", string.Empty);
// !return.ObjectV,.Value
```

Comment: I have an issue with removing characters. Could you pls take a look at my updated post?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do it like this:

```
strValue =  strValue.Substring(0, strValue.LastIndexOf("rgm")) +
    strValue.Substring(strValue.LastIndexOf(";1"), strValue.Length);
```

This way you get the first part and the second part then concatenate them together. This will work if you have only one instance of these characters.

Comment: This throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception because it sum of two index positions exceeds string length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. First find "rgm" and ";1" position, then remove characters between these indexes.

```
int start = strValue.LastIndexOf("rgm");
int end = strValue.LastIndexOf(";1");
string str = strValue.Remove(start, (end-start)+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.IndexOf()` and `string.Replace()`

```
        var i = strValue.IndexOf("rgm");
        var j = strValue.IndexOf(";1");
        var removePart = strValue.Substring(i, j - i);
        strValue.Replace(removePart, string.Empty);
```